# Auto close non responding , unknown or frozen Game

Tags: batch-file

My batch file is supposed to auto exit my game if it freezes or isn`t booting , which happens from time to time as it's finicky due to the RE Engine. Solution would be to have the game auto exit as soon as there's less than 10% Cpu usage or if its not responding or unknown status.

This is what I've got so far in my batch file:

```
@echo OFF
start "" "Autolaunch DMC5 aka Steam, required for Playing.ahk"
TIMEOUT /t 20
start "" "steam://rungameid/601150"
TIMEOUT /t 30
start /min "" "DMCVTrainer.exe"
start /min "" "SSSiyanCollabTU5.CT"
set "process_name=DevilMayCry5.exe"

::remove .exe suffix if there is
set pn=%process_name:.exe=%

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set c=0
:: getting three snapshots of CPU usage of the given process
for /f skip^=2^ tokens^=3^ delims^=^" %%p in ('typeperf "\Process(%pn%)\%% Processor Time"  -sc 3') do (
    set /a counter=counter+1
    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=." %%a in ("%%p") do set  "process_snapshot_!counter!=%%a%%b"

)

:: remove rem to see the cpu usage from the three snapshots
rem set process_snapshot_

:: if all three snapshots are less than 0000010 process will be killed
if 1%process_snapshot_1% LSS 10000010 if 1%process_snapshot_2% LSS 10000010 if 1%process_snapshot_3% LSS 10000010 (
     tskill %pn%
)
:RUNNING
tasklist|findstr DevilMayCry5.exe > nul
if errorlevel 1 (
    timeout /t 1
    taskkill /F /IM cheatengine-x86_64.exe
    taskkill /F /IM DMCVTrainer.exe
    taskkill /F /IM Steam.exe
) & GOTO ENDLOOP
timeout /t 1
GOTO RUNNING
:ENDLOOP
exit /B
```

wont let me update because my code isnt in proper format.

Comment: and if possible , since windows explorer tends to crash with it every so often , maybe have it autoclosed on non responding and restarted

Comment: what? i need a solution to my batch , said function doesnt work and i recon the values might be wrong as well for the cpu percentage , not to mention as said , id like to have the batch autoexit dmc5 once its below 10% cpu usage or it throws a not responding message or unknown also if its still running but it freezes aka throws a application has stopped working including a WerFault message at you

Comment: a solution would be appreciated , btw forget about the windows explorer restart , got a separate app that does this now , the rest still stands , btw if possible add a timer to not responding , a 1 minute timer, before not responding gets closed would be neat

Comment: Instead of complaining about not getting an answer, how about you post the solution as an answer to your own question, so that it is helpful for others in the future? That's how SO works, and it is about both taking and *giving*. That said, with only a single tag `batch-file`, it is highly unlikely that any respondent able to help ever actually saw the question - you should use tags to target possible respondents (`windows`, maybe?).